# How to get to_json work on BSON::Code object as well in mongo-ruby-driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb, nosql

I am trying 'mongo-ruby-driver' for some project. It's working fine except when I call to_json on mongo object. It gives well formed json but it's not converting BSON::Code into readable value i resulting JSON.

Instead of showing code text, it show something like

```
#<BSON::Code:0x00000100af6fa8>
```

Did anyone tried it. Any help id highly appreciated.

UPDATE

here is some code snippet:

@records is variable that contains Array of MongoDB documents in hash.

```
@records.to_json
```

When I call to_json on it it gives everything as expected. except for the key that contain BSON::Code (means javascript code). for example consider following doc:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "contains", 
  "value" : function( obj, target ) { return obj.indexOf(target) != -1; }; 
}
```

Querying same doc from ruby gives output like:

```
{
  "_id"=>"contains", 
  "value"=><BSON::Code:2160165280 @data="function( obj, target ) { return obj.indexOf(target) != -1; };" @scope="{}">
}
```

and calling to_json on this gives following:

```
{"_id":"contains","value":"#<BSON::Code:0x00000100b54658>"}
```

this is what the problem is. Instead of getting actual code for 'value' key I am getting ruby object as string.

Calling code method on BSON::Code we can get it converted into code. But for that I need to loop mongo docs, check values for each key, calling code on it if it is an object of BSON::Code and then assigning it back to key. And at last we can call to_json on it. But I dont want this much overhead. I need to_json itself should take care of it.

Comment: Can you update the answer with your code?

Comment: Yes, I updated question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer that is iterating over the attributes of the objects in the array is probably calling the to_s method which would cause the output you are seeing.

You can either monkey patch the BSON::Code class to include a to_s method which calls inspect (the method that produces the output you want) or modify the serializer to detect when it encounters a BSON::Code instance and call inspect on it rather than to_s.

The code to mokey patch the BSON::Code class would look like this:

```
module BSON
  class Code
    def to_s
      inspect
    end
  end
end
```

This would have the same behavior as inspect. If you just wanted the code you could monkey patch this in:

```
module BSON
  class Code
    def to_s
      @code
    end
  end
end
```

I might make this the default behavior for to_s in the driver but for now just include that in your code and it should work like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

Which Mongo object, do you mean the module? If you could, please post the code and what you are trying to do.

The only to_json I see in the driver is BSON::ObjectId#to_json which (from the docs) is described as a method that does the following:

> Convert to MongoDB extended JSON format. Since JSON includes type information, but lacks an ObjectId type, this JSON format encodes the type using an $oid key.

I get the same results when I use it:

```
1.9.3-p0 :001 > require 'mongo'
 => true 
1.9.3-p0 :002 > BSON::ObjectId
 => BSON::ObjectId 
1.9.3-p0 :003 > BSON::ObjectId.new()
 => BSON::ObjectId('4f17350eadd361e91d000001') 
1.9.3-p0 :004 > BSON::ObjectId.new().to_json
 => "{\"$oid\": \"4f173512add361e91d000002\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

BSON ( http://bsonspec.org/ ) is a binary representation of JSON ( http://www.json.org/ ) .  JSON is not meant to be used to describe functions, as it is meant to be portable.  Functions in this manner are not portable to other systems.  So there is no way to serialize it.  There is some hacks defined here that may get you what you need, but ultimately, BSON/JSON may be a weird tool for the job if your trying to serialize functions.